# Convergence of Lipschitz functions in $L^\infty$ implies the convergence in $H^{1}$

Tags: proof-verification, sobolev-spaces, uniform-convergence, holder-spaces

Suppose $f_n \to f$ in $L^\infty(U)$ where $f_n, f \in C^{1,1}(\bar{U})$, (Holder space with $k=1, \alpha =1$, i.e, Lipschitz functions) where $U$ is an open and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Q: Can we say that $f_n \to f$ in $H^{1}(U)$?

I think it is indeed the case. Here is my attempt. 
Since $U$ is bounded, we can upper bound $L^2$-norm by $L^\infty$ so that
\begin{align}
\|f_n - f\|_{H^{1}(U)}^2 &= \|f_n - f\|_{L^2(U)}^2 +\|Df_n - Df\|_{L^2(U)}^2
\\
&\le \mu(U)\|f_n -f\|_{L^\infty(U)}^2 + \|Df_n - Df\|_{L^2(U)}^2.
\end{align}
Thus, it suffices to show the convergence of $\|Df_n - Df\|_{L^2(U)}^2$.

Since $e_n = f_n-f \in C^{1,1}(\bar{U})$, (if needed let assume $U$ is convex), the derivative of $e_n$ is bounded by its Lipschitz constant:
$$
\|De_n\|_{L^\infty} \le \text{Lip}(e_n) = \sup_{x,y \in U, x\ne y} \frac{\|e_n(x)-e_n(y)\|}{\|x-y\|}.
$$
Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $x', y' \in U, x'\ne y'$ such that 
$$
\text{Lip}(e_n) \le \epsilon + \frac{\|e_n(x')-e_n(y')\|}{\|x'-y'\|}
\le \epsilon + \frac{2\|e_n\|_{L^\infty(U)}}{\|x'-y'\|} \to \epsilon \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
$$
Since $\epsilon$ was chosen arbitrarily, we conclude that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \|De_n\|_{L^\infty(U)} = 0,
$$
which shows that $f_n \to f$ in $H^1(U)$.
**[Edited: This proof is false, as $x'$ and $y'$ depend on $n$].**

It seems that the above derivation is correct. On one hand, the result seems quite strong. Normally, one cannot have the uniform convergence of $\{f_j'\}$ from the uniform convergence of $\{f_j\}$. 
At first glance, at least for me, this seems quite a surprising result. 
On the other hand, however, it sort of makes sense, as $\{f_j\}$ is Lipschitz and differentiable - $\{f_j'\}$ is somewhat well controlled.
I would like to make sure of the rigourousness of the above argument.

Any comments/answers/suggestions will be very appreciated. Thanks!

**[Here I added my second attempt.]**
Since $f_n \in C^{1,1}$, $f_n, f_n'$ are Lipschitz functions.
By applying Arzela-Ascoli theorem in $\{f_n'\}$, we have a uniformly convergent subsequence $\{f_{n_k}'\}$. 
By invoking the [standard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability), that $\lim_{k\to \infty} f_{n_k}'(x) = f'(x)$. Since the limit is unique, we conclude that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n'(x)=f(x)$.

**[2nd Edited: An additional Assumption is needed];**
In order to ensure the uniform boundedness of Lipschitz constants of $\{f_n'\}$, it seems that I need to assume that $\{f_n\}$ is a bounded sequence in $C^{2,1}(\bar{U})$.

Comment: When you substitute $\|e_n(x')-e_n(y')\|$ by $2\|e_n\|_{L^\infty(U)}$, the bound explodes to infinity.

Comment: I mean that $x'$ and $y'$ depend both on $\epsilon$ and $n$ and you have no way to control how small  $x' - y'$ becomes.

Comment: Note that your $x’,y’$ depend heavily on $n$: they can get arbitrarily closer as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @tst I see. Is there any way I can fix the proof? Or do I need a stronger condition than $C^{1,1}$?

Comment: @induction601 I'm not sure what you mean by fixing the proof. I think the statement is false. Take your favorite counter example to the statement "a pointwise convergent sequence of continuous functions is continuous", take the antiderivative of the functions in the sequence and I believe you have a counterexample of what you are asserting.

Comment: @tst I was thinking to use the Arzela-Ascoli theorem on $f_n'$. Since $\{f_n\}$ and $\{f_n'\}$ are Lipschitz ($f_n \in C^{1,1}$), at least we have a uniform convergent subsequence $\{f_{n_k}'\}$. Then, each subsequence, it seems that we can use the standard theorem to show $\lim_{k\to \infty} f_{n_k}'(x) = f(x)$. Since the limit is unique, the claim seems to be proved.

Comment: @induction601 you assume $L_\infty$ convergence for $f_n$, but not for $f'_n$. How would you get a uniform bound in that case?

Comment: @tst You mean the uniform boundedness of Lipschitz constants of $f_n'$?

Comment: @induction601 yes

Comment: @tst I see. You're right. I think I should assume that $\{f_n\}$ is a bounded sequence in $C^{2,1}(U)$. Then, $\{f_n''\}$ is now bounded. Does this assumption sound solid?

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false:

Define $f=0$, $f_n(x) = n^{-1}\sin(n^2\pi x)$ on $(0,1)$. Then these functions are Lipschitz, $f_n \to f$ in $L^\infty$, but $(f_n)$ is even not bounded in $H^1$.